# Error while taking backup using "spatie/laravel-backup" and using destination disk as Google Drive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using **Laravel 5.4** and **spatie/laravel-backup** v3 and **flysystem-google-drive**

> "nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive": "~1.1"
>
> https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

I am able to upload files using

```
Storage::disk('google')->put('FileName.txt', "hello world");
```

But with Spatie/laravel-backup package I'm getting the following error while using destination disk as **'google'**.

Can you help me regarding this?
[image]
**Filesystem:**

```
'google' => [
        'driver' => 'google',
        'clientId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'clientSecret' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'refreshToken' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
        'folderId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is Common Bug When Dealing With [Laravel-backup](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v5/introduction) And [flysystem-google-drive](https://github.com/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive) What I Did To Solve This Problem In Production .

1. Go To Your **.env** File :

   - Change APP_URL=http://localhost To APP_URL= http://YourDomainName
2. Go To Your /config/backup.php

   - Change The Line

     'name' => config('app.name'),
     //To 
     'name' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),

Now You Should Receive Your Backup

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error "message": "File not found: 6666666Jo8AWLW-LI-XSR5n4z_7KVfNer."

The reason is in the name of the folder that was generated by Google Drive.
Because when I created a new folder, it had a new name "888888RrZx-wXq91XVWd9ZsfrK8X6-yZ" - everything worked.

I think the problem was because of the underscore in GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID.

Answer (score 0):

only pass null name in backup.php

```
'name' => config('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID' , ''),
```

like this will be resolved

```
 'backup' => [

        /*
         * The name of this application. You can use this name to monitor
         * the backups.
         */
        'name' => config('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID' , ''),

        'source' => [
```